# How to use a dynamically loaded interface with reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to use reflection to dynamically load Log4j2 libraries and method. The goal being to have my program use Log4j2 if it is found in the class path and to simply log to console if Log4j2 was not found. It works well with the standard log methods, but I can't find how to use the ones with suppliers.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.function.Supplier; // This java 8 interface happens to have the same signature as the Log4j2 Supplier interface

public class Test() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Starting by loading Log4j2 classes and methods
            ClassLoader classLoader = B.class.getClassLoader();
            Class<?> classLogManager = classLoader.loadClass("org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager");
            Method methodGetLogger = classLogManager.getMethod("getLogger");
            Class<?> interfaceSupplier = classLoader.loadClass("org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Supplier");
            Object logger = methodGetLogger.invoke(null);
            Method methodFatal = logger.getClass().getMethod("fatal", interfaceSupplier);

            // Now trying an ugly trick, but it does not work
            Supplier<String> fatalSupplier = new Supplier<String>() {
                @Override
                public String get() {
                    System.out.println("fatal log was evaluated");
                    return "fatal";
                }

            };
            methodFatal.invoke(logger, fatalSupplier);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I get of course the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Is there any way to create an object matching the Supplier interface (the Log4j one) without loading statically any Log4j2 class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it fails is that `java.util.function.Supplier` is not a sub type of `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Supplier`.

Replace the line

```
methodFatal.invoke(logger, fatalSupplier);
```

by

```
Object newProxyInstance = Proxy.newProxyInstance(classLoader, new Class[]{interfaceSupplier}, new InvocationHandler() {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        //TODO check method
        return fatalSupplier.get();
    }
});
methodFatal.invoke(logger, newProxyInstance);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. I am going to carefully read documentation about these classes I did not know.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implementing your own abstract logging layer, I would suggest that you use an existing one, such as:

- [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) with [Log4j 2 SLF4J Binding](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html) (recommended)
- [Apache Commons Logging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) with [Log4j Commons Logging Bridge](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-jcl/)

Both of those will do what you want, i.e. be able to replace the *actual* logging library simply by changing the .jar files on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know those tools, maybe I will use one of them instead of writing my own tool.

Answer (score 1):

How do you plan on using this?

Using reflection to invoke Loggers is not going to be pretty. If your goal is to create an abstraction the easiest way to do it would be to create your own interface and then create an implementation that uses Log4j 2 and another that doesn't. Then create a factory that checks for Log4j 2 on the class path and then binds the correct implementation to your application based on that.  Then your adapter code can be written directly against Log4j 2.

But I also agree - why not just use SLF4J or Commons Logging?

Comment: Not using SLF4J or Common Logging mostly because not knowing them... Now I have to check what they can do and maybe they will perfectly fit.